# Is there a way to detect small lines using the threshold function in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read a heavily compressed jpeg image and transform that into a clearer threshold image like this:

Input image

[image: jpeg image]

To good threshold image

[image: good threshold image]

but because of the jpeg compression, the image has smaller lines so the result of the threshold is this:

Bad threshold image

[image: bad threshold image]

I want to have an image with that also has the smaller lines in them so how would I do that?

right now I'm using the opencv threshold function to make the image black and white and then I use erosion to make the lines a bit bigger.

```py
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (thresh, BlackWhite) = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    kernel = np.ones((4, 4),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(BlackWhite, kernel,iterations = 1)
    cv2_imshow(erosion)
```

Comment: `dilation = cv2.erode(BlackWhite, kernel,iterations = 1)` Maybe actually use `dilate` instead of `erode`, which is the exact opposite?

Comment: oh ill edit that, i forgot that i used erosion and not dilation

Comment: Then the rest of your sentence doesn't make sense any more, since erosion makes your lines thinner. By your `4 x 4` rectangular kernel, the two pixel wide gray lines of the window in the upper left room will always disappear for example, although their values are above 150 in the original image. Maybe, leaving out erosion at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code for your questions try it it will work fine with u :)

```
 def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
        # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
        v = np.median(image)

        # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
        lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
        upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
        edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

        # return the edged image
        return edged

    image = cv2.imread('asd.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 0)
    edges = auto_canny(blur)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 3, 255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cv2.imshow('thres',thresh)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: You should never use somebody else's code in your answer without referencing it. The code you posted was clearly taken from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/), yet you didn't reference it.